# WPF WebBrowser NavigateToStream & images

Tags: wpf, browser

I'm planning to use thw WebBrowser component to display html that is created on the fly. The perfect choice for this is NavigateToString or NavigateToStream methods. There's only one single problem - I need to load images / css styles / js files too. How do I accomplish this while using string/stream?

As an option I'm also considering writing/finding simple http server and running it on some port, but that's an additional work and requirements(open ports) so I'd like to avoid that if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast WebBrowser.Document to IPersistMoniker and load a moniker that implements GetDisplayName. Check http://csexwb2.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cEXWB.cs for example code.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with this same problem I created my own solution.  You can see it here:
[Reference an image imbedded in a WPF application from within an HTML file used as help content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533767/reference-an-image-imbedded-in-a-wpf-application-from-within-an-html-file-used-a/17555751#17555751)